# Embed font programmatically from ttf file to .docx file using docx4j

Tags: java, fonts, docx4j

I have a spring boot project and I am using docx4j 8.1.5
Looking for a way to programmatically embed a font from a .ttf file that I have in my resources
when editing a .docx file.

I have checked this [Programmatically embed fonts to document in docx4j (during XHTML - DOCX conversion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627376/programmatically-embed-fonts-to-document-in-docx4j-during-xhtml-docx-conversi)
but did not understand what exactly has to be done .

If anyone done something like this a code example will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Word generally obfuscates an embedded font; see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/WordprocessingML/ObfuscatedFontPart.java#L89 for how docx4j reads such a part.

To embed a font, you'd expect you need to reverse this process.

But [2.1.268 of [MS-OE376]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/6b99ea32-290c-48c8-b78a-78c4a841c47a) suggests that the font key may be optional for Word 2010 and later; in other words, you may be able to add a font without needing to obfuscate it.